# Open New Tab / New Window

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, href

i am unable to open file in new window.any one help me regarding this issue

```
 echo '<a href="'. $fileStorage . $row['file'] .'">'. htmlentities('Click Here', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') .'</a><br />';
```

where to write `target='_blank'` in the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add [`target`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) attribute:

```
echo '<a href="'. $fileStorage . $row['file'] .'" target="_blank">'. htmlentities('Click Here', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') .'</a><br />';
```

> `_blank` => Opens the linked document in a new window or tab

Answer (score 1):

use target="_blank" for open in new tab like

```
 <a href="{url}" target="_blank">{anchor Data} </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this target="_blank" in  tag..

```
<a href="" target="_blank">your text</a>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked. OP knows what needs to go in, they are simply unsure on where to put it.